# How to convert json properties that are formatted in dot notation to a c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using `HttpClient` to retrieve data from an api. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the property names, they were all written in dot notation, for example

```
"staff":[{"responsible.user":"Y","staff.type":
    {"staff.type.mnemonic":"C","staff.type.name":"Consultant"}]
```

There is probably at least 100 or so properties in this json callback that are like this.
I need to return back a json object that removes the dots (i.e. change `responsible.user` to `responsibleuser`)
Is there a way to map a c# class and return the format I want back?

I have a c# class using the `[DataContract]` attribute and `[Datamember(Name=)]` fields to map the values, but when I look at the json that is returned, they still have the dots in the properties.

This is what I started to work with in my controller

```
 using(HttpClient c = new HttpClient())
        {
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
               new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                   "Bearer",
                   "Cazqmx-TTHOOfnJy92SRng=="
               );
            var link = string.Format(AmsApiGet, "6894998", "TYEE");
            var res = await c.GetStringAsync(link);
            TaskAPI task = new TaskAPI();

            task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskAPI>(res);

            return Ok(task);
```

Basically, I am just trying to convert the property names, so that I can use typescript models in my frontend Angular side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the property names received by the front end by transforming the data into your own POCO (Plain Ol' C# Object) before converting it to JSON.

```
TaskAPI task = new TaskAPI();

List<myPOCO> list = new List<myPOCO>();

foreach (var item in res)
  list.Add(new myPOCO(item)); //all your mapping is in the POCO Constructor

task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(list); //or whatever syntax it would be
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to do something similar, I just played around with copying the properties of my TaskApi class into a new class, remove the data contract in that class, then use automapper to return the json back to how I want it to look